# How to use pybullet createConstraint for constraining world frame position of an object

Tags: python, physics, scientific-computing

`createConstraint` method in **pybullet** allows to constrain one joint position w.r.t. another. Is there a way to use this function in order to prevent an object moving e.g. outside of a sphere?

So far I am checking the object position every timestep and change the position manually in case of violated constraints.

Comment: What is "w.r.t." ?

Comment: @pak [_with respect to_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/what-does-wrt-mean)

Comment: Do you mean the standard bullet constraint does not converge well?  It currently acts like elastic rubber?  You want something more stiff?

Comment: @javaLover well, not at all. I am asking how to implement a constraint for an object w.r.t. world frame using pybullet

Comment: Blender (open source) uses python for interface and also use Bullet.  I feel that it has constraint too.  There is *a little* chance that it contains code that uses pybullet for constraint.   Hope it helps. .... It tends to hard to use *ported-version* of a library (In C++ Bullet, the constraint is easy & well-documented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact there is a working example in the file examples/pybullet/constraint.py of pybullet.